My cat is moving my other cats litter
My cat had a litter June 23 and we kept one of the litter, now my cat has had another litter and the cat we kept is trying to relocate them while the mother cat is away from them. Could someone please help with why she is trying to nurse/relocate her “siblings”

Either disagreement about the best place for them, or she wishes she had kittens...

I would be concerned this could be the start of aggression/territorialism from the other cat
